# Check if two lists are different in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
diverso([X|L1],L2) :- nonp(X,L2), diverso(L1,L2).
nonp(X,[]).
nonp(X,[A|B]) :- X\=A, nonp(X,B).
```

this is my code, it doesn't work and I don't know why.
Error is

> Diverso/2 unknown predicate

My query is:

```
?-diverso([3,4],[1,2]).
```

Comment: You're missing the recursive base case for `diverso`

Comment: You're totally right. I can't even believe. Thank you

Comment: No problem! Let me know if that solves your problem and I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Yeah. It works diverso([],Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the recursive base case for the `diverso` predicate solves the problem!